# Facing Issue while Sharing Video using Facebook SDK in android

Tags: android, facebook

I tried to share images using facebook sdk in android app - works like charm but when i tried to share video nothing happens.

The following is the code that i'm using for sharing video content:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch(v.getId()){
        case R.id.fb_share_button:
            ShareVideo shareVideo1= new ShareVideo.Builder()
                    .setLocalUrl(Uri.parse("https://imdstar.com/clubapp/wp-content/uploads/2017/07/Chennaionline-AirtelParallelMusicFestival106-online-video-cutter.com_.mp4"))
                    .build();


            ShareVideoContent shareContent = new ShareVideoContent.Builder()
                    .setVideo(shareVideo1)
                    .build();
            shareButton.setShareContent(shareContent);
            shareDialog.show(shareContent, ShareDialog.Mode.AUTOMATIC);
            break;

        default:
            break;
    }


}
```

The method is getting called on clicking share button but no dialog box appears for sharing.Please give me your valuable suggestion where i'm commiting mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are trying to share a link but you are using the code to share a video which is on your device.

Please have a look at

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/android

and try to use the code for sharing a link

```
ShareLinkContent content = new ShareLinkContent.Builder()
        .setContentUrl(Uri.parse("https://developers.facebook.com"))
        .build();
```

Please take into account that you have to use the Facebook Share Button. Please see at the bottom of https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/android

```
ShareButton shareButton = (ShareButton)findViewById(R.id.fb_share_button);
shareButton.setShareContent(content);
```

You cannot use the standard Android Button